# Как применить стили к children через event на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, html, события

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(event.target.children.style.pointerEvents = "none")
})
```

Comment: children - коллекция, обойдите её и сделайте то что нужно со всеми элементами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов как это можно реализовать:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const children = event.target.parentNode.children
  if (children) {
    Array.from(children).forEach(child => {
      child.style.color = "red"
    })    
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <p>DIV 1 - Line 1</p>
  <p>DIV 1 - Line 2</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>DIV 2 - Line 1</p>
  <p>DIV 2 - Line 2</p>
</div>
```